# Firefox fullscreen animation is too slow

Tags: gnome, firefox

The firefox fullscreen animation is too slow for me.  I have a relatively small screen, so I want a quick way to fill my screen with content.  How do I make the animation faster?

Version: firefox-58.0.2-1.fc27.x86_64 (Fedora Linux 27)

### Additional clues

I have two separate user accounts.  One of them is fine, but the other is too slow.

In one of the user accounts, I have notes suggesting that I set `browser.fullscreen.animateUp` as mentioned by [this article](https://lifehacker.com/the-best-about-config-tweaks-that-make-firefox-better-1442137111).  However, this setting can no longer be found in `about:config`.

In both user accounts, I use GNOME and have enabled the Impatience extension to GNOME, set to 0.66 of the default delay.  I have notes suggesting that this was also a very useful step to help with Firefox fullscreen animation specifically.  I can see no other settings in Impatience.  Setting the delay to zero does not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Firefox 77, there is no config option for this.

There may be a more complex solution: https://superuser.com/questions/1558881/how-to-disable-firefox-address-bar-animation-on-fullscreen/1560428#1560428

### Before Firefox 77

`browser.fullscreen.animateUp` was removed at some point.  Instead, you can edit the preference `toolkit.cosmeticAnimations.enabled`.

---

Found by searching for `anim` in `about:config`.  (And also, in the good profile I clicked on the "Status" column to sort it so all the "modified" preferences were together, so I could see that this particular "anim" preference was one that I had changed).